# simpleXML_load_file. No response online

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I try to connect with server which is shut down with the command `simplexml_load_file()` in a php script.

When I try from my computer with **WAMP SERVER**, I get this error :

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://......link....): failed to open
>   stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

which it is fine. If I use `@` I can handle the warning and do whatever I want.

The problem is, that if I upload and run the script online, I get nothing back with or without `@`, neither `false`.

So, I can not handle the error. I do not know if the time is up or it is something else.

I want to handle the error and online.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: you can use CURL to check availability of server before using simplexml_load_file function

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php to check for errors.

```
libxml_clear_errors();
$doc = simplexml_load_file('http://....');

if (!$doc) {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();

    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        // Do something
    }

    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

Comment: This had the same results.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the same result'? There were no errors reported and $doc is null?

Comment: Sorry for no responding yesterday. Please, see the answer below.

Answer (score -1):

You should wrap your call to simplexml_load_file() with a try...catch block.

```
try {
    simplexml_load_file('http://www.whatever.com');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // You can deal with (or ignore) the error here.
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: `simplexml_load_file` does not throw exception in his case. It issues a warning, but only local server. This won't help at all.